# Как вывести данные из БД в разные блоки?

Tags: php

```css
.content .articles {
 display:flex;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 
}
.content .articles article{
 max-width:40%;
 margin:1%;
 min-height:300px;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="articles">
     <article>
     <?php
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($news); $i++) {
  echo '
    <img src="img/'.$news[$i]["id"].'.jpg" alt="" title="">
    <h2>'.$news[$i]["title"].'</h2>
    <p>'.$news[$i]["text"].'</p>
    <h5>'.$news[$i]["date"].'</h5>
    <a href="article1" title=""> Читать далее</a>
     '
   ;}
     ?>
     </article>
</div>
```

Как вывести новости из БД в разные блоки? Я вывожу новости и в итоге получается, что они друг на друге в одном css блоке, а я мне надо, чтобы они были в отдельных блоках.

```
<?php
require_once "connect.php";

function getNews ($limit) {
    global $mysqli;
    connectDB();
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT*FROM `news` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT $limit");
    closeDB();
    return resultToArray($result);
}
function resultToArray($result) {
        $array = array();
        while(($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) != false)
            $array[]=$row;
        return $array;
}
```

?>

Comment: Из приведенного кода невозможно разобрать суть вопроса. Покажите CSS и HTML

Comment: Сделайте так чтобы тег article был внутри цикла

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался, но появился еще один вопрос, теперь все 4 новости выстроены в ряд в одном блоке <div class="articles">, как сделать чтобы отображалось по 2 новости на одной строке?

Comment: Разобрался, большое спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="articles">

  <?php foreach($news as $article){ ?>

    <artilce> 
      <img src="img/' . <?=$article["id"];?> . '.jpg" alt="" title="">
      <h2> . <?=$article["title"];?> . </h2>
      <p> . <?=$article["text"];?> . </p>
      <h5> . <?=$article["date"];?> . </h5>
      <a href="article1" title=""> Читать далее </a>        
    </article>

  <?php } ?>

</div>
```